# Problems debugging initializer?

Tags: xcode, debugging, swift, init, lldb

I have a debugging error on the following code:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

Here is all of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 50, 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"thumbsUp.png"), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "thumbsUpButtonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func thumbsUpButtonPressed() {
    println("thumbs up button pressed")
}
```

The error says:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

The debugger output says the following:

`fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file...hi/ViewController.swift, line 14`

I have had this error before and am unsure of how to fix it. The weird thing is, there was an error saying `You don't have any initializers` and had me put it in. It is giving me an error either way (with it or without it).

Any input and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you trigger a "fatalError" instead of initializing. Replace

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

with

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: Why did it have me enter the code if it makes it crash?

Comment: Thanks though. It worked. I just want to know some background info.

Comment: I guess adding this crashing line (by triggering fatalError with a message about a missing coder) is the Xcode way of telling you that you indeed need to implement this coder in this class. I agree that this can be confusing.